# offline installation of an Android PLATFORM on Windows?

Tags: android

Okay so I have followed instructions on earlier questions in order to offline install the Android SDK, platform-tools and tools, and now I am trying to install an Android platform. (When I run "android list targets", it returns that there are no available targets, and the platforms folder is empty).

What types of files are actually IN the platforms directory? I have files from the repository like "system.img" and "kernel-qemu", but I don't know where to put them.

Could someone let me know what their C:\Android\platforms folder structure actually looks like for a working installation?

(NB: for background, I am able to get to the URL "dl-ssl.google.com" through my browser and even the Eclipse internal browser, but for some reason it can't be accessed from the SDK manager, so I can't download any components or platforms!!)

Comment: the url might be also available with http instead of https.. maybe that fixes your problem...

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose you want to install android platform? If you want to develop apps, you need a lot of stuff from platform folder except "system.img" and "kernel-qemu": android.jar, ant tasks, tools and a lot of resources. If you want just to run emulator, you probably need not all of that...

This is contents of my platform folder: http://ccfit.nsu.ru/~izhovkin/list.txt