# installing android offline is hard[obsolete]

Tags: android, eclipse, offline, android-sdk-2.1

i am a student in africa and in our land, there actually exist slow and expensive internet connections, which is why we tremble in fear  whenever we hear the word "online repository" method of installing software. Damn, that usually means you have to look elsewhere.

**The problem.(i cant install android without connecting eclipse to the internet)**

It is possible to manually download individual components as .zip files but there is no way of installing them into android eg i have managed to download

- platform-tools_r03-windows

  android-sdk_r10-windows

  etc

but no matter what i do, i can't get android to recognise them as components. It seems **tens of thousands of other developers have a similar problem (see below)**

[This qn has 10k views(meaning 10k people had a similar problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install)

[another lost developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862366/offline-installation-of-an-android-platform-on-windows)

[webpage sudgesting solution that failed to work on windows seven ultimate](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html)

If someone has actually ever installed android without connecting eclipse to the internet, please let us know the magic you used. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

if someone out there is still interested check out http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html
and make sure your folder structure is as shown in http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: The first question you linked to has an answer with 11 upvotes which the asker accepted. This implies that it solved their problem. Have you tried that?

Comment: 10k view just means 10k views.  You have no idea if the people viewing it had the same/similar problem or not.  I'm viewing your question and I don't even use Android.  However, your larger point about too casually assuming everyone has a fat broadband connection for web-based installs is valid.

Comment: @jason: sorry for that assumption. But generally i think people tend to view a question if they have a similar problem since theyre more likely to find it interesting

Comment: @eldarerathis: i did. The thing is you are able to download the zip files separately but not able to integrate them into android sdk manager or eclips

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For **SDK** and **platform tools** you can just extract the zip content, Eclipse has nothing to do here.

For **Eclipse ADT** plugin:

1. Download the zip file from http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip
2. *Help* -> *Install New Software* -> *Add*
3. Select *Archive* and then provide the location of the zip file

These steps are clearly explained in [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) documentation.

Comment: i installed eclipse adt plugin with no problem at all. The problem is with installing the things that have to be installed using the android sdk and avd manager where your solution does not apply.

Comment: i was forced to manually see where each folder should be placed relative to the sdk. eg to install the docs, i had to download them then extract them to a specific position in the sdk directory. Offline install i guess are a pain. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Only in Windows**

1. Install (if not installed) Oracle JDK jdk-7-windows-i586.exe
   install Eclipse SDK
2. Add to the PATH environment variable the path to the JDK (for example c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin)
3. Edit the file hosts (c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts), add the entry "127.0.0.1 dl-ssl.google.com"
   It's important! Port 80 must be free at the time of installation Android SDK
4. Run the Abyss Web Server X1 (abyssws.exe). Works best if you download a fresh copy
5. Run the Android SDK "SDK Manager.exe" installer
6. In the "Android SDK Mannager" in the menu "Tools" >> "Options" put the check ("force https:// ... sources to be fetched using http:// ...")
7. Android SDK Manager will fetch packages in your computer. Choose the packages for API you want to program against, select and install packages
8. After installation the file hosts (c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) entry "127.0.0.1 dl-ssl.google.com" you entered in step 3
9. Good Luck!! and remember to update to lastest APIs and revision

**You can download Eclipse ADT and install**

1. IN Eclipse: Click Help tab and Install New Software tab
2. Click add button
3. In Add Repository Window, add in Name Field Eclipse ADT and Location field  click archive to browse in local machine where you downloaded ADT
4. Press Ok and tick all, Eclipse will install the less

Answer (score 0):

The answer by dtmilano is not valid for the current version of android SDK. (androdi 4.2.2)

The android website says that after the unzipping of the ADT:

*Your Eclipse IDE is now set up to develop Android apps, but you need to add the latest SDK platform tools and an Android platform to your environment. To get these packages for your SDK, continue to Adding Platforms and Packages.*

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Instead, try
http://qdevarena.blogspot.in/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html

as mentioned by
[Installing android SDK in eclipse offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039471/installing-android-sdk-in-eclipse-offline)

Answer (score 0):

I'M a Ghanaian..I did it about a week ago on ubuntu it might work on windows

your question indicates that you have eclipse installed..so i will just move on to setting it up to run android apps ...

step 1: go to developer.android.com to download the sdk for windows(i recomend you download the one with the installer).
step 2: launch ur favourite browser and open this [site](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml).

you will see an xml page using ctr+f (any shortcut for finding a text on your browser) type andoroid 2.2 or any android version you like latest is kitkat 4.4...you will find ur prefered android version in zip file for ur OS i.e windows...just copy the text and append it to this [address](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml).

this will download the the platform for you in .zip format....just navigate to where you extracted ur sdk and go to platform folder and then create a new folder with any name and then extract the platfor you downloaded earlier i.e android version into the new folder you created...just launch the sdk.exe and it will auto detect your platform for you...

just go and creae your Android virtual device and start running your apps..