# Installing android SDK in eclipse offline

Tags: android

I want install android on my computer but using the sdk it fails to download the packages due to my speed i think. I have extensively googled for several days but could not find any result i found a page which showed a way using the abyss server to install but lost it due to  a powercut and could not find it again.
If any one could share a link or a tutorial of installing android sdk and using it with eclipse would be great help.

Comment: you can download first and then set up the environment:http://techbreaths.com/2012/12/setting-environment-android-app/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try following Step in Process of making Android Development Environment .

I hope you have already Eclipse .if you don't have then get it from here and  Latest Eclipse is Version 3.7.[Eclipse for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2)

Step 2: As you have problem of internet speed try to Download Zip File of Latest ADT tool from this. [Android ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) 
  Use this ADT Zip describe in this SO -->[SO link ADT install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690840/installing-android-offline-is-hard)
after done with add zip in Eclipse you need internet connection.

STEP 3: Now for Android SDK you can download this android-sdk_r17-windows.zip which have small size from this Developer Site -->[Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

when you put this Zip in your computer and unzip it and Download one of Android SDK Platform from this Site -->[SDK Platform Offiine](http://qdevarena.blogspot.in/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html).

STEp 4: Now when you get one of SDK Platform you need to put that in this for Example in my PC .I have following path .

```
  E:\Android_development\android-sdk\platforms\put here your SDK Platform Folder.
```

your path of android-sdk may different .

STEP 5: don't forgot give Path of your Android-SDK to here in Eclipse.For give path go here in Eclipse

Window-->Preferences-->Android  now in SDK Location Box
Provide Location of Android SDK Some thing like this

```
  E:\Android_development\android-sdk
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on steps 4 and 5 as i placed my platforms folder in android sdk like "I:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4.0.3" but these changes are not reflected after performing step 5

Comment: @cornercoder you have installed ADT plugins in your Eclipse and as you said that when you give path of android-sdk  to Eclipse ,it does not show you any android Platform in list.make sure you have put unzip folder of android-4.0.4 in `android-sdk\platforms\`.

Comment: yes i have put the unzipped folders bro..this thing is now really depressing me

Answer (score 0):

Go to **http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml**, and select the sdk platform version you want to install and then copy paste the appropriate platform `android-x_rxx-windows/linux/macosx.zip` you want to setup,

```
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-x_rxx.zip
```

- After you download it, go to your
  SDK-Installation-Path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms` in Windows). Create a Folder named android x and extract all zip contents into the android x folder.
- Close the SDK Manager and reopen it. You will find the SDK platform for the android x will be shown as installed.

This tutorial explains it in detail,

[How to install android sdk platform offline](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6588/how-to-install-android-sdk-without-internet-connection/)